# Xpages - Java - How to start writing code

Tags: xpages

I am new to Java but not Lotus Notes. Here are some of my questions:

1. Main method in Java class - Can I run a simple HelloWorld.java in DDE as I would in Ecplise?
2. Do I use Java design element or create Java classes in project explorer?
3. Would it be better to uninstall other JVMs before starting on working Java in DDE?

Thanks
Arun

Comment: What do you want to do with Java in Lotues Notes Environment? Do you want to develop Xpages? Standalone Applications? Java Agents?

Comment: I want to be able to test my java code (small chunks in this way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to play with Java (not the XPages part) create a Java project in Domino Designer (change to the Java perspective) and then use the main to write code. When you run it as a Java program it will output to the console. You can still access Domino objects. For example, the code below shows how to do that... I did this to test out some data models and concepts and then copied the code to an actual NSF for use as a bean after I proved out my concept. It is so much easier to experiment and test running your code as a Java program and viewing the output in the browser.

Howard

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            NotesThread.sinitThread(); // start thread
            Session s = NotesFactory.createSession((String) null, (String) null, "cessna");
//do whatever

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            NotesThread.stermThread(); // must terminate every thread
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Howard. This is what i have been trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to invest some time to learn how Xpages and Java are used in DDE/Notes/Domino as:

- the JVM of IBM is completely separated from other JVM you may have installed
- Java classes don't have a main method - except you refer to those that come from an Agent
- if you create a Java class for an XPages app you always use the Java class element

A good point to start is David Leedy's [NotesIn9](http://www.notesin9.com/) series. You can check the whole compendium of video tutorials here: http://www.mindmeister.com/de/280533435/notesin9

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I feared as much (about main method). So no workaround there.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question with XPages my answer will cover only Java development in DDE for XPages.

1. You can't use the main method as usually. Create a HelloWorld.java with a static methode hello() and call this method in an XPage with `{javascript:com.package.HelloWorld.hello()}`
2. You can use Java design elements. Those are easy to access in DDE and included in build path already. For larger projects you can create your own directory structure in Package explorer and include those in build path. As long as they included in build path you can use them in XPages.
3. The JVM is included in and get used from Domino server. You don't need to uninstall JVM on your computer.

Comment: Thanks Knut. I know this but as commented above I want to be able to test my code without having to run whole program again and again. Debugger is one option but using it a challenge in itself if you do not have Domino server running locally.

Comment: I recommend using a local Domino server on your computer. That is the best way to develop, to test and to debug as you don't depend on administrators and server settings you can't change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by not wanting to run the whole program. The "program" is the same XPages runtime you'll have been running when writing SSJS. The JVM is created as part of that runtime, for a specific NSF. That runtime includes all the relevant OSGi plugins on which a lot of your Java code will depend (thinks like FacesContext classes, ExtLibUtil etc). Testing of "the program" in XPages is usually no different to testing of "the program" in traditional Notes development.

You can test from Eclipse, but you need to be able to connect to a Domino server in order to run the code in a similar way to how you need to be able to connect to a Domino server to run the debugger. So if running the debugger is an issue, running from Eclipse is a non-starter.

From Eclipse, unless you're running code from a OSGi plugin, you'll still need to copy and paste your code outside the NSF, unless you use test cases within the ODP.

If you want to run junit tests, an OpenNTF project is available for that. But from my experience of Java and junit testing, I don't think I would have been capable of using that to test my code when I was just starting out with Java. So it's not something I'd recommend.

Static methods (utility methods that are not in a managed bean) can be tested from standalone XPages. I've used that method before. Otherwise, beans can be added to a standalone XPage pointing to whatever data you wish or initialised with whatever values you wish, so you have the control to test part of it, if the application architecture allows it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how JVM is created for every database. And you are right about Ecplise thing, tried it for long but ultimately gave up. I used to connect to Domino server using CORBA and write programs but could not port those back to NSF.
Also, I was not able to use JAR design element for external JARs (was trying for json.org API for JSON handling). It keeps saying could not find class.
Thanks again.

Comment: The last problem - the NoClassDefFoundError - is likely to be a security problem. Access to interact with the server's OS is restricted by the java.policy restrictions outside the NSF. This question may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157168/xpages-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-cannot-find-class-org-apache-commons-h

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and post results.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the article "the double headed beast" from Bob Balaban. It explains the approach you want to take. While it was written for agents it applies to Java too.

What you need to do: write your businesses logic (the part you want to unit test) without dependencies to xpages specifics. Hand over the key objects in method calls: session database. You can initialize them in a main routine.

I wrote an article about that, [Check it out](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-98U9EK).